# How to format HTML from a URL in xamarin to display in web view?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I'm trying to load this URL   http://challonge.com/lhswaterwarslosersbracket1/module in a web view but I want to get rid of the bottom_bar because it displays an add in my app and to just generally learn if I can edit web pages in my app. I'm using Xamarin forms and the HTML agility package.

```
public void ViewBracket()
    {


        WebView webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = new UrlWebViewSource
            {
                Url = "http://challonge.com/lhswaterwarslosersbracket1/module",
            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        // Accomodate iPhone status bar.
        this.Padding = new Thickness(10, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 10, 5);


        // Build the page.
        this.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                //header,
                webView
            }
        };

    }
public async void DownloadHomepage()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
       // var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://challonge.com/lhswaterwarslosersbracket1/module").ConfigureAwait(false);

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var bottombar = doc.GetElementbyId("bottom_bar");



        Debug.WriteLine(html);

    }
```

Comment: so you're stealing content from a website and removing the ads that they use to pay their bills?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn how to edit the HTML in xamarin that's all, but to answer your question pretty much yea, and it's not like I would be the only one as there is an unofficial Challengo app on the play store that displays the bracket without ads I'm just trying to replicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTMLWebViewSource https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#HTML_Strings